# Refresh table after ajax POST based on search criteria

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

All,

I have a modal that contains a table with results from a PHP query using PHP include, the problem is as the modal is loaded when the page if first opened, I appear to be unable to use an AJAX post later on to refresh the table based on a textbox variable.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">    
        <div id="divSearchResultsTable">
            <table  class="tblSearchResults" id="tblSearchResults">     
                <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th> 
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        include("sql_search.php");
                    ?>
                <tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="divSearchResultsButtons">
            <input type="button" class="btnOpen" id="btnOpen" name="btnOpen" value="Open" disabled="true"/>
            &nbsp
            <input type="button" class="btnClose" id="btnClose" name="btnClose" value="Close"/>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSearch').click(function(e){
        var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        var value = $("#txtSearch").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "sql_search.php",                 
                    data : {value:value},
                    success : function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                        modal.style.display = 'block';
                        modal.focus();
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

PHP (sql_search.php)

```
$value = (isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : null);

if ($value == null){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM helpdesk";
}

else{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM helpdesk WHERE ID = $value";
}

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>' . '<td>'.date("d/m/Y g:i:s A", strtotime($row['DateCreated'])).'</td>' . '<td>'.$row['Priority'].'</td>' . '<td>'.$row['Company'].'</td>' . '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>' . '<td>'.$row['Subject'].'</td>' . '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

The result I am getting is every database item returned. I've used `alert(output)` in my AJAX success to confirm the varible is actually being passed, so I think I now just need to work out how to get the table to update.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see the table with ID `modal`. You are getting it in your JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include your PHP file in html, but assign an id to the element where you'd like to have its output. Then in Javacsript, populate the content with the data returned by AJAX call.

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">    
        <div id="divSearchResultsTable">
            <table  class="tblSearchResults" id="tblSearchResults">     
                <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th> 
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="modalContent">
                    <!--  note, no content and tbody has an ID -->
                <tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="divSearchResultsButtons">
            <input type="button" class="btnOpen" id="btnOpen" name="btnOpen" value="Open" disabled="true"/>
            &nbsp
            <input type="button" class="btnClose" id="btnClose" name="btnClose" value="Close"/>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSearch').click(function(e){
        var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        var value = $("#txtSearch").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "sql_search.php",                 
                    data : {value:value},
                    success : function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                        $('#modalContent').html(output);  // <------
                        modal.style.display = 'block';
                        modal.focus();
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

BTW, your PHP code is unsafe as it uses its parameter directly in SQL query without validation or type casting (SQL injection) and outputs data from database without escaping html (stored HTML/Javascript injection). Consider using PDO with parameters - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php and wrap database output values into htmlspecialchars() call

Comment: Thanks for you help, this works fine now and I'm getting the expected results however the rows are no longer selectable. Here is the JavaScript used to make the row selectable, is there something that needs changing now to get this to work. I've currently only made the changes you recommended. Thanks `$(function(){
  
  $("#tblSearchResults tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
  });  });`

Comment: I worked it out, I just needed to move some of my code around and place it under the 'success:' function. Thanks again for your help and the tip with the unsafe PHP code. I will look to fix that up :)